# how to display all JSON values in android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I'm currently studying this tutorial http://www.android-examples.com/android-json-parsing-retrieve-from-url-and-set-mysql-db-data/

It runs perfectly but now I would like to display all of the JSON values in the text view. I am new to JSON and only has a bit of experience in android.

Here is my MainActivity.java. I modified it a bit from the tutorial

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView textview;
JSONObject json = null;
String str = "";
HttpResponse response;
Context context;
ProgressBar progressbar;
Button button;
JSONArray jArray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progressbar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            new GetTextViewData(context).execute();

        }
    });
}

public static Map<String,String> parse(JSONObject json , Map<String,String> out) throws JSONException{
    Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();
    while(keys.hasNext()){
        String key = keys.next();
        String val = null;
        try{
            JSONObject value = json.getJSONObject(key);
            parse(value,out);
        }catch(Exception e){
            val = json.getString(key);
        }

        if(val != null){
            out.put(key,val);
        }
    }
    return out;
}

private class GetTextViewData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    public Context context;

    public GetTextViewData(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
    {

        HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.9:80/test-androidex/send-data.php");

        try {
            response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
            str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
            json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);

        } catch ( JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {

     try {
           textview.setText(json.getString("name"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}
```

and this is my JSON. It is a lot different from the tutorial

> [{"id":"1","name":"white","status":"0"},{"id":"2","name":"red","status":"10"},{"id":"5","name":"blue","status":"15"}]

So obviously my code only displays the first name "white". I can't understand how to iterate the JSONObject to display all the values. I tried the answers in other questions but I can't quite incorporate them in my code.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're just getting the first element from `JSONArray`. (Index 0)

You should iterate over `JSONArray` to get all the `JSONObject` within an array.

**Like this,**

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
int total=jArray.length();
for(int i=0;i<total;i++) {
    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i); // Replace 0 with i'th index.
   // use this json object to iterate over individual objects.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNLSGubX3B4)'s example of json parsing and insert , update , delete or get data from server with source you should try this !

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your code is what Alok Patel stated. But I see that the logic of your code needs some changes to do what you want (according to sample json that you posted). You called parse method on values which are in fact simple data while you should call it on jsonObjects.

I refactored your code as below to do what you want:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView textview;
JSONObject json = null;
String str = "";
HttpResponse response;
Context context;
ProgressBar progressbar;
Button button;
JSONArray jArray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progressbar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            new GetTextViewData(context).execute();

        }
    });
}



private class GetTextViewData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    public Context context;
    Map<String,String> out = new Map<String, String>();

    public GetTextViewData(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
    {

        HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.9:80/test-androidex/send-data.php");

        try {
            response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
            str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
            int total=jArray.length();

            for(int i=0;i<total;i++) {
                 JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
                 parse(json, out);
            }

        } catch ( JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {

     try {
         // print "out" object to console here by iterating over its keys 
         // or do any needed process on it here.
           textview.setText(json.getString("name"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
Map<String,String> parse(JSONObject json , Map<String,String> out) throws JSONException{
    Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();
    while(keys.hasNext()){
        String key = keys.next();
        String val = null;
        try{
            val = json.getString(key);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }

        if(val != null){
            out.put(key,val);
        }
    }
    return out;
 }
}
```